# Get corresponding values to a select in a group for PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

(Background: I'm attempting to find the "peak" hour of activity in a series of cameraapis, defined as having the most entries with a start and end date between 1 hour periods (starting with the beginning of the hour)  For example, 1:00 to 2:00 may have 8 entries within that timeframe, but 2:00 to 3:00 has 12 entries - so I would want to have it return the 12 entry timeframe.)

I'm having trouble getting associated data from a SELECT query of a group.  Here is the code:

```
def reach_peak_hour_by_date_range(start_date, end_date)
  placement_self_device_id = self.device_id
  query = <<-SQL
  SELECT max(y.num_entries) AS max_entries
  FROM
  (  
    SELECT x.starting_hour, count(*) AS num_entries
    FROM
    (
      SELECT date_trunc('hour', visitor_start_time) starting_hour
      FROM Cameraapis WHERE device_id = '#{placement_self_device_id}'::text AND visitor_start_time > '#{start_date}'::timestamp AND visitor_end_time < '#{end_date}'::timestamp
    ) AS x
    GROUP BY x.starting_hour
  ) AS y
  SQL
  results = Placement.connection.execute(query)
  binding.pry
end
```

Cameraapi have a device_id, visitor_start_time, and visitor_end_time, referenced in the code.

This code successfully returns the max_entries in a 1 hour period, but I can't figure out what to SELECT to get the associated starting_hour to that max_entries.  Because it is a group, it requires aggregated functions, which I don't actually need. Any advice?

Comment: have you considered putting that part into ruby?

Comment: your question needs more context, it's a little hard to decipher as is. But why not use the aggregate function : array_agg(expression) in your select statement to extract the ids you need ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

didnt quite understand the question ... use window  functions

```
    select starting_hour  , num_entries from (
     SELECT   starting_hour ,y.num_entries, max(y.num_entries) over() AS        max_entries
     FROM
     (  
       SELECT x.starting_hour, count(*) AS num_entries
       FROM
       (
         SELECT date_trunc('hour', visitor_start_time) starting_hour
         FROM Cameraapis  WHERE device_id = '#{placement_self_device_id}'::text AND visitor_start_time > '#{start_date}'::timestamp AND visitor_end_time < '#{end_date}'::timestamp
       ) AS x
       GROUP BY x.starting_hour
     ) AS y 
   ) as u
   where num_entries = max_entries
```

this query returns all entries associated with peak hour, you can modify it to return only entry count with associated hour selecting hour and count using distinct or grouping

```
    select * from 
(
select   x.*, max(num_entries) over()as max_num_entries  from 
(
    SELECT  Cameraapis.* ,date_trunc('hour', visitor_start_time) as starting_hour, count(*) over( partition by  date_trunc('hour', visitor_start_time)) as num_entries
    FROM Cameraapis WHERE device_id = '#{placement_self_device_id}'::text AND visitor_start_time > '#{start_date}'::timestamp AND visitor_end_time < '#{end_date}'::timestamp
) as x
) as x where  max_num_entries = num_entries
```